# Azure DownloadGitHubRelease@0 looking for version tag even after versionType is set to latest

Tags: azure, azure-devops

- task: DownloadGitHubRelease@0
  displayName: 'Github download'
  inputs:
  connection: 'xxx'
  userRepository: 'xxx'
  defaultVersionType: 'Specific Tag'
  version: $(xx-version)
  downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

even setting 'latest' in userRepesitory requires version tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Specific Tag as defaultVersionType. According to [this document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DownloadGitHubReleaseV0/README.md#parameters-of-the-task):
Default Release version type: The version of the GitHub Release from which the assets are downloaded. The version type can be 'Latest Release', 'Specific Version' or 'Specific Tag'.

- Release: This options shows up if 'Specific Version' or 'Specific Tag' is selected as Default Release version type. Based on the version type selected, Release name or the Tag needs to be provided.

Here is my sample:

Tags in github:

[image]

Yaml:

```
  - task: DownloadGitHubRelease@0
    inputs:
      connection: 'github'
      userRepository: '***/***'
      defaultVersionType: 'specificTag'
      version: '1.0.1'
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

You can select latest release as default version if you want to download the latest release.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `The release version/tag input 'null' is not valid` even when using `latest` when my GitHub access token had expired.